# how to send small files(<10Kb) of large quantity(300,000 files) to external drive quickly?

Tags: file-transfer

I have lots of javascript files(~300,000) which has size of <1Kb. I'm trying to tranfer it to external harddrive. It is taking days to transfer. Please let us know if there is any quick way to do this.

Comment: use copy programs that can buffer files first and then write back them in bulk mode. one good choice is "fastCopy" that works in windows. you can adjust buffer size as you want.

Comment: How is this a programming question? The fact that the files happen to be Javascript files doesn't make the question on-topic here. Try [su] instead.

Comment: i dint put this question under Javascript for your info. @http://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a compressed archive, like a .zip file, then transfer that.

Comment: Tried that. Compressing is taking a lot of time. Since it has small files